# NSAlert - can you have a custom icon?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsalert

Is there a way to insert a custom icon in a NSAlert? I know you can have different prefabbealert styles but is it possible to cu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can use

```
- (void)setIcon:(NSImage *)icon
```

Look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
let alert = NSAlert()
alert.messageText = "My message"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
alert.alertStyle = .informational
alert.icon = img
alert.runModal()
```